# Migrating Vaadin Portlet from Liferay 6.1 to Liferay 6.2 ga6

Tags: liferay, vaadin, liferay-6

I am trying to migrate a portlet from Liferay 6.1 to Liferay 6.2 ga6. This portlet has also Vaadin integration version 7.6.5. I am getting this error and I need help figuring out how to proceed:

```
.... 
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:682)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet.handleRequest(VaadinPortlet.java:544)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet.serveResource(VaadinPortlet.java:626)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:122)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:82)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
......
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Max

Comment: Have you replaced the vaadin.jar that was supplied in the ROOT/WEB-INF/lib folder with the 7.6.5 vaadin jar files?

Comment: Hi @ChrisM, thanks for answering. Yes the files are there, downloaded with maven dependencies (sorry didn't mention that).

Comment: Did you also create a new VAADIN folder with widgetset, themes and vaadinBootstrap.js

Comment: Yes. It is exactly as it was on Liferay 6.1. with 2 folders, themes and widgetsets, but not the vaadinBootstrap.js. Where do I place it and where from can I obtain it?

Comment: It's in vaadin-server.jar I think

Comment: You need to put it in /webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN along with vaadinBootstrap.js.gz